# Switch from Armature Weight Paint to Hair Weight Paint?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, hair

In Weight Paint mode, how do I switch from painting the armature to hair?  I am stuck on armature, and want to paint emission instead.

Answer (score 0):

Weight paint mode doesn't paint "armatures" or "hairs". It paints "vertex groups" which are used in any way, may it be an armature, particles, objects relationships, modifiers influences, ...

So, to make it simple: you just have to choose which vertex group you want to work on, from the vertex group panel in your object data tab:

[image: demo pic]

Comment: Thank you!!  I really appreciate your help